# Unhide column when in edit mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I'm attempting to use material table editable feature `onRowAdd`.

Some of the columns in my table are hidden using `hidden: true`.

My goal is to unhide the columns when entering the editable mode.

I know that there is an option to combine the two using `options={{columnsButton: true}}` that allows to hide or unhide the columns while in edit mode but I want to force the table to show all the columns on add.

Is there a way to set the hidden value based on the edit mode?
Or a possibility to force the columns to show on edit?

Comment: did you get any lead in this?

Comment: Sadly not, I went on a different styling direction and instead of hiding the columns I used opacity to make them less visible - The above issue still remains unsolved.